# Asp:Image with Link

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to place an image in my application. when I click on it I want to move to another page. In general my asp:image to work as link
Is that possible ??

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use an `ImageButton` with a server side click event:

```
Response.Redirect("SecondPage.aspx");
```

Or alternatively, you could wrap a `Hyperlink` control around the `Image` control:

```
<asp:hyperlink id="link" runat="server">
   <asp:image id="img" runat="server" imageurl="..." />
</asp:hyperlink>
```

Or just use a HTML anchor tag if you don't need the link to be dynamic:

```
<a href="..">
   <asp:image id="img" runat="server" imageurl="..." />
</a>
```

Comment: Yeah stopped using LinkButtons a long time ago!

Answer (score 21):

You can add an ImageUrl to a HyperLink.

```
<asp:HyperLink id="link" runat="server" imageurl="..." />
```

Answer (score 4):

sure it's possible

```
<a href="Somepage.aspx"><asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server" /></a>
```

Or if you want code-behind to handle which page you're linking to use [asp:ImageButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx)

```
<asp:ImageButton id="ImageButton1" runat="server" />
```

and handle the click event in your code-behind

Answer (score 0):

Surround your Image with an anchor tag, like this:

```
<a href="urlofmypage">
<asp:Image............ />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ImageButton  and on click button do a redirect to the page that you want to go to.

Answer (score 0):

asp:image has own link control. Check it.