# Dynamic imageURL in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

At the moment i have this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl2.ascx.cs" Inherits="Drawing.Usercontrols.WebUserControl2" %>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" alt="Image Not Found" ImageUrl="~/images/k8up7l1i.bmp"/>
```

in the webUserControl2.ascx page.

In WebUserControl2.ascx.cs page, all of the logic is found. An Image is generated there, and then saved to a path (C:\Work Drawing\Drawing\Drawing\images)
 where:

```
string thisPathName = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Images/" + randomFileName);
```

My question is, can i call a method "getPathName()" from the asp page (where ImageUrl is, instead of a static URL). So each time i call it, the new image will be displayed in the browser with that pathname generated in the c# code?

Please notify me if the question was unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the answer is Yea , you can .

let's assume you have this function in code behind:

```
public string getPathName(){
    return "my_image_path.jpg";
}
```

by that , you can have this in the form :

```
<img alt="Image Not Found" src="<%=getPathName()%>"/>
```

and there you go . you get you'r image path from the code behind .

good luck .

Comment: Splendid! However, the page displays "image not found", it also doesn't seem to call the method when i put breakpoints.

<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" alt="Image Not Found" ImageUrl="<%=getPathName()%>"/>

        public string getPathName() { 

            string pathName = "~/images/k8up7l1i.bmp";

            return pathName;
        }

Do i need to initiate or invoke something?

Comment: no you don't need to invoke something . you just need to change the img from server tag to html tag . check the edited answer

Comment: It is following my breakpoints now with the edited code, which is good!
Except that image not found is still displayed whilst using the mentioned pathname as a hardcoded parameter.

Comment: client side html tags do not understand what is ~ means . you should specify the full path .

Comment: Cool it seems to work now.

<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" alt="Image Not Found" ImageUrl="<%=this.getPathName()%>"/>

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
Image1.ImageUrl = getPathName();
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
        public string getPathName() { 
            return "~/images/" + randomFileName; //where randomfilename = 12341263.bmp  for example
        }
-=-==-=-=-=-=-==-=-

Comment: This section doesnt allow proper makeup, sorry.

Comment: if you find my answer as the final answer mark it as Answer .

Comment: i dont know if it is fair towards przemG since he basically posted the same answer simultaniously.

I can mark yours, do you, by any chance, also know if it is possible to make the image clickable so it does something in my c# code (not open a html link).

You dont have to answer it i can look it up

Comment: it's easy . check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167839/aspimage-with-link  and of course you  can use image button as well !

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign function call result to server control property (like ImageUrl) unless that control is within data-bound control like GridView or Repeater.

What you can do is to set ImageUrl in code behind e.g. in PageLoad event:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = getPathName();
```

or, if you want to do it from asp page and you don't need to reference Image1 from server, render it as html element:

```
<img alt="Image Not Found" src='<%= this.getPathName %>' />
```

getPathNmae must be 'protected' or 'public' for above to work.

Comment: It is following my breakpoints now with the edited code, as mentioned in the other comment. Except that image not found is still displayed whilst using the mentioned pathname as a hardcoded parameter.

I have yet to try the Image1.ImageUrl = getPathName(); solution, i wonder if it is possible to change the images like this dynamically in runtime