# asp link to open image on displayed image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, hyperlink

I've got an asp image in a repeater control, and I used the marked answer found here to get it so it links to the actual file:

[Asp:Image with Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167839/aspimage-with-link)

Specifically, I surrounded it by an asp:hyperlink:

```
<asp:hyperlink id="link" runat="server">
   <asp:image id="img" runat="server" imageurl="..." />
</asp:hyperlink>
```

This solution worked perfectly.  However, when I tried to click on the link in IE, it immediately downloaded the image and then prompted me with options at the bottom to open or save the file.

Is there any way to have that hyperlink just open the image on a new page?

Comment: You want to click that image and have that image open in a new page? new tab?

Comment: I'd like to have it pop up, preferrably, but I'll take anything but an instant download.  Same page, new page, whatever ya got.  And the target idea didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use js:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server">
    <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl="~/images/app/your-img.png"
        onclick="openWinPopUp(this.src)" />
</asp:HyperLink>

<script>
    function openWinPopUp(URL, w, h, t, l) {
        var wdh = (w == null || w == "" || w == "undefined") ? 250 : w;
        var hgh = (h == null || h == "" || h == "undefined") ? 160 : h;
        var tp = (t == null || t == "" || t == "undefined") ? 200 : t;
        var lft = (l == null || l == "" || l == "undefined") ? 100 : l;
        window.open(URL, "blank", "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no," +
            "status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes," +
            "resizable=no,copyhistory=no," +
            "width=" + wdh + ", height=" + hgh + ", left =" + lft + "," +
            "top = " + tp + ";");
    }
</script>
```

Tested on MS Edge.