# How to hyperlink an image in asp.net (C# / vb.net)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, pdf

I have a webpage in which I am trying to hyperlink an image. The screenshot of that section of the webpage is as follows:

[image]

On clicking the pdf image, it should open a pdf.

At this moment, I am able to create a `pdf image` which is local to my machine.

The code in .aspx file are:

```
<div class="row" id="divViewAssessment" runat="server">
   <div class="itemtitle">
      <asp:Label ID="litBlankAssessment" runat="server"></asp:Label>
   </div>
   <div class="itemdata">
      <asp:ImageButton ID="btnViewAssessment" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/doc_pdf.gif"
         CausesValidation="False" ValidationGroup="vgrp1" Enabled="true"></asp:ImageButton>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am wondering what code do I need to put in `.aspx.vb` file ? I am sure what I need to put in `.aspx` but not sure what need to put in `.aspx.vb (behind the code)`.

The path of the pdf local to my machine is `"~/Licensee/" + CStr(Session("LicenseeCode")) + "/ViewSA/Lebanon Primary Care Standards for SW.pdf"` The LicenseeCode is `MPHLB`.

Comment: Don't you just need to change the ImageUrl to that path?

Comment: @ADyson Maybe, I am not that much verse with asp.net but I am wondering is there anything I need to put in .aspx.vb ?

Comment: Ah wait ok I got it, the image is just a thumbnail, you want it to download the actual file. You want the button to point to the PDF. So yeah you need to go find out how to start a file download in ASP.NET, plenty of tutorials.

Comment: @ADyson I have created an image and on clicking that image, it should open a pdf in different  tab. The path of the pdf local to my machine is **"~/Licensee/" + CStr(Session("LicenseeCode")) + "/ViewSA/Lebanon Primary Care Standards for SW.pdf"** The LicenseeCode is **MPHLB**

Comment: Or replace the imagebutton with a hyperlink to the file, with an image instead of text within the hyperlink. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167839/aspimage-with-link

Comment: @ADyson Ok, I will do that but is there anything need to do **.aspx.vb** ? or just changes only in **.aspx** ?

Comment: @ADyson Yes, the image is just a thumbnail. On clicking that image, I will open the pdf in different tab.

Answer (score 2):

The `ImageButton` control is intended for triggering a postback, not navigating to a URL.

Use a `HyperLink` control instead. It has an `ImageUrl` property to set the image that is displayed, and also a `NavigateUrl` property to set your target URL.

Comment: Alright I will do that and will show you soon what I did.

Comment: This is what, I have done


 `<div class="row" id="divViewAssessment" runat="server">
                <div class="itemtitle">
                    <asp:Label ID="litBlankAssessment" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </div>
           <div class="itemdata">
                <asp:hyperlink id="~/Licensee/" +"MPHLB"+ "/ViewSA/Lebanon Primary Care Standards for SW.pdf" runat="server">
                  <asp:image id="img" runat="server" imageurl="~/Images/doc_pdf.gif" />
                </asp:hyperlink>
           </div>
            </div>`

Comment: The error which I got is **The server tag is not well formatted** at line `<asp:hyperlink id="~/Licensee/" +"MPHLB"+ "/ViewSA/Lebanon Primary Care Standards for SW.pdf" runat="server">`

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are doing. Why are you creating a complex string for the `id`? The `id` is the name you give to the control and cannot contain punctuation or spaces. Also, you don't need an `Image` control there. Why did you do that? Please reread my answer because I don't think you got it. Finally, if you have a complex URL that you want to set the `NavigateUrl` property to, then I guess you'll need to do that from code. (One more note: if you drag the control to your form, it will enter the basics for you. It looks like you need some help there.)

Comment: This is what I have done and it working as well.   

`<div class="itemdata">
               <asp:hyperlink id="link" runat="server">
                  <a href="Licensee/MPHLB/ViewSA/Lebanon Primary Care Standards for SW.pdf">
                    <asp:image id="img" runat="server" imageurl="~/Images/doc_pdf.gif" />
                </a>
               </asp:hyperlink>
           </div>`

Let me know if this can be improved.

Comment: @flash: I don't know why you can't understand my answer. Add a `HyperLink` control to your form. Set the `ImageUrl` attribute to the URL of your image. Set the `NavigateUrl` attribute to the URL to your PDF file. No `<a>` tag is needed. No `Image` control is needed. Sorry, but I don't know how to make it more simple than that.

Comment: @JonathanWood  My apologies for that. I have made slight changes after your comment. Let me know how it looks.   `<div class="itemdata">
             <asp:HyperLink ID="SALink" runat="Server" NavigateUrl="/Licensee/MPHLB/ViewSA/Lebanon Primary Care Standards for SW.pdf" ImageUrl="~/Images/doc_pdf.gif" Target="_new" ToolTip="Lebanon Primary Care Services SA" />
           </div>`

Comment: That's what I was expecting. Does it work john/flash/whateveryournameis?

Comment: @JonathanWood Yes it worked. I followed this tutorial http://www.dotnetfunda.com/tutorials/controls/hyperlink.aspx

Comment: @JonathanWood. The code which I just sent is written in HTML (**.aspx**). Just for clarification, I am wondering if there any changes I need to do in vb file (**.aspx.vb**)

Comment: No, unless the NavigateUrl can change. You could set that or any property from code. But if the code in your comment works, then that's all you need. In fact, that approach is efficient because it doesn't need any server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code..

```
Protected Sub btnViewAssessment_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnViewAssessment.Click

    Response.Redirect("Lebanon Primary Care Standards for SW.pdf")

End Sub
```

**Put your pdf in solution folder.**

Comment: This will work, but it's far less efficient. It causes a post back of the current page and the server to issue a redirect whereas a regular link simply provides a URL the browser can navigate to directly.

Comment: Ok, what you want me to put **.aspx** file ?