# I would like to add a label to a gridview that includes text and and image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview, hyperlink

I want to add a link and image to a gridview when certain conditions are met.

I think that it can be done using the below code, but I get confused about where the " go and I know that some of them need to be \" but I'm not sure where. At the moment this won't compile, please could someone help me with this?

I've also investigated using an image button but that way seems more complex in my case, as the button should only appear in rows that fit the conditions. I'm open to using that method instead if you think that it's better.

```
if(line.SuperSessionIndicator == "1" || line.ErrorType =="S" )
            {

             lbl3.Text = "<aref=\"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167839/aspimage-with-link \">"<img url='Images/Prop.png\'/>\"\"<a/>"; 

            }
```

Comment: Checkout the answer I have posted. It should compile and emit valid html text.

Comment: `aref` is a typo, you should use `a href` for anchor tag instead.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thank you, I made the typo copying it from VS into Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use following code to get it right.

```
lbl3.Text = "<a href=\"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167839/aspimage-with-link\"><img src='Images/Prop.png\'/><a/>";
```

The resulting markup from above C# code would be as below which looks correct.

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167839/aspimage-with-link"><img src='Images/Prop.png'/><a/>
```

Comment: thanks again I needed to change it to "img src" rather than "img url", correcting my own mistake from earlier. Works fine now. Your help is appreciated as always.

Comment: Yes,  for IMG element you need to use src attribute and not url.

Comment: I have updated my code to use src attribute.